# Japid: Strange behavior when getting value of a key from HashMap

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, japid

```
<p> THAT'S OK: ${((Map<String,Integer>)view.get("upgrade_assignment_type_map")).toString()} </p>

<p> THAT'S ALSO OK:
for( String _name : ((Map<String, Integer>)view.get("upgrade_assignment_type_map")).keySet() ) {
<p> ${_name}: ${((Map<String, Integer>)view.get("upgrade_assignment_type_map")).get(_name)} </p>
}
</p>
<br><br>
<p> SADLY THAT'S NOT OK::: ${((Map<String, Integer>)view.get("upgrade_assignment_type_map")).get("MANUAL")} </p>
```

The above code segment prints following output which is surprising for me:

```
THAT'S OK: {AUTO_WITH_BALANCE_EMPHASIS=2, AUTO_WITH_OFFENSIVE_EMPHASIS=0, MANUAL=3, AUTO_WITH_DEFENSIVE_EMPHASIS=1}

THAT'S ALSO OK:

AUTO_WITH_BALANCE_EMPHASIS: 2

AUTO_WITH_OFFENSIVE_EMPHASIS: 0

MANUAL: 3

AUTO_WITH_DEFENSIVE_EMPHASIS: 1



SADLY THAT'S NOT OK:::
```

The last line of code segment tries to get the value of key "MANUAL" but it's not printing the value and if I try to convert it to toString (like `${((Map<String, Integer>)view.get("upgrade_assignment_type_map")).get("MANUAL").toString()}` ) it gives me null at runtime. I don't understand why it's happening?

and when I print the length(after first colon `<p> ${_name}: ${_name.length()} : ${((Map<String, Integer>)view.get("upgrade_assignment_type_map")).get(_name)} </p>` ) of each key I got:

```
AUTO_WITH_BALANCE_EMPHASIS: 29 : 2

AUTO_WITH_OFFENSIVE_EMPHASIS: 29 : 0

MANUAL: 10 : 3

AUTO_WITH_DEFENSIVE_EMPHASIS: 30 : 1
```

Note: I am creating map inside java source as `Map<String, Integer> nameToTypeMap = Maps.newHashMap();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse was not showing invalid characters and there were invalid characters (which were surprisingly compilable) in those string, so when I opened that particular file in vim, it shows me and I removed those invalid characters. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the "MANUAL" entry has an unprintable character somewhere in it. Change one of your working lines like this:

```
<p> KEY_LENGTHS:
for( String _name : ((Map<String, Integer>)view.get("upgrade_assignment_type_map")).keySet() ) {
<p> ${_name}: ${_name.length()}</p>
</p>
```

If that shows MANUAL with a length other than 6, that suggests I'm right, and you should look at your data source to work out where the extra character is coming from.

If not, I would at least try to debug this *outside* the HTML part. I haven't used the Play framework, but presumably there must be some code populating this view... if you can break into a debugger there, it's likely to make it a lot easier to diagnose.

Another possibility is that the entry contains a non-ASCII character which *looks* like an ASCII character, but actually isn't. If you look at the source of the HTML, you may be able to see that (and *possibly* even the unprintable character, depending on how it's handled).

Comment: @gmuhammad: Don't put all of this into comments. Edit your question instead. (If you're *really* doing that in Java code, that's very strange.)

Comment: I put the has map code and the length output in my question. But can you please explain why it's happening?

Comment: @gmuhammad: No, you didn't - you made an edit with no real content. I suggest you debug into your Java code, checking the original string.

Comment: I am getting error "body is missing" if i try to put more code in question so I am putting it here:  
   nameToTypeMap.put("AUTO_WITH_OFFENSIVE_EMPHASIS", AUTO_WITH_OFFENSIVE_EMPHASIS.getType());
   nameToTypeMap.put("AUTO_WITH_DEFENSIVE_EMPHASIS", AUTO_WITH_DEFENSIVE_EMPHASIS.getType());
   nameToTypeMap.put("AUTO_WITH_BALANCE_EMPHASIS", AUTO_WITH_BALANCE_EMPHASIS.getType());
   nameToTypeMap.put("MANUAL", MANUAL.getType());

Comment: I debug the above hash map and length of each key in the above map is same as in the view. So I guess I need to do something special when getting data from that map. am I right?

Comment: @gmuhammad: You still haven't put the details in the question... but it sounds like you're doing something strange when constructing the map... as if your string literal of "MANUAL" actually contains the non-printable characters.

Comment: I am creating map using `Maps.newHashMap()`, which is I think google specific libraray. Is that the reason?

Comment: @gmuhammad: No, absolutely not. And you *still* haven't put this construction code into your question.

Comment: It's there now, actually I was having problem editing the question at that time, and comments are not editable after some time. Now I put that.